# getting new code coverage, new issues history in time machine api

Tags: web-services, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube5.3, sonarqube-web

We have a requirement to get historical information on new code coverage, new issues for sonar projects. The resources api gives value  of only the last analysis while the time machine api is giving value=null for these new code metrics:
https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/timemachine?metrics=complexity,coverage,blocker_violations,critical_violations,new_line_coverage,new_coverage,new_blocker_violations,new_critical_violations&includetrends=true&resource=org.sonarsource.php%3Aphp

What is the correct way to retrieve historical information on new code metrics using API. We are usng SonarQube 5.3 version

Comment: The history of new XXX measures are not kept. Why did you need them ?

Comment: we have more than 100 applications in our sonar instance that are being actively developed by different teams.This information will allow us to track how different teams are making code changes so we can provide feedback for improvement

Comment: +1. Even though new code coverage is a differential metric (and is kind of intuitive that no one would ever need its history), my organization wants to keep track of how frequently developers are meeting the delta code coverage threshold. Keeping this history would be very valuable for us.